# How can I "scan" an image at a set DPI using a camera?

Tags: camera, scanner

I want to scan a check so I can upload it to my bank's website for electronic deposit. The bank requires the image to be a JPG of at least 200 DPI. Unfortunately, I do not have a scanner, just a camera.

Can I take a picture of the check and still have it meet the above requirements?

Comment: If you have an android phone, you can try to *scan* the check using camscanner! Just in case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard personal check has a size of `6 x 2.75` inches. At `200` DPI, the resulting image in **pixels** would be `1200 x 500`.<sup>**1**</sup>

Therefor, you should be able to meet your bank's requirements if you crop a picture of the check and the remaining image is at least `1200 x 500` pixels in dimension.

One thing to note, however, is the bank may require the DPI to be in the image's metadata. You can use [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) to format the image with **Image > Print Size** and setting the parameters appropriately:

[image: print size]

---

<sup>**1**</sup> *"[dots per inch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch)" is synonymous with "pixels per inch" in this case.*

Comment: If your camera is capable of 1.5 megapixels or more, it should be able to meet the resolution requirements, assuming the check fills the frame to the extent possible.